# A distance function between music playlists

Tags: distance, metric, distance-functions

I am looking for a way to measure the dissimilarity/distance $d$ between a set of music playlists $\{P_i\}$ with possibly different number of songs. We may assume that a playlist contains a specific song at most once.

It would be nice (although not necessary) if some of the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $d(P_i, P_i) = 0 \quad \forall i$
2. $d(P_i, P_j) > 0 \quad \forall i \neq j$
3. $d(P_i,P_j) = d(P_j, P_i) \quad \forall i,j$
4. $d(P_i,P_j) = d(P_i,P_k) + d(P_k,P_j) \quad \forall i,j,k$
5. If two playlists have all songs common except $n$ songs, then if playlists' size get bigger, the distance get smaller.

Comment: Do you already have a way of measuring the distance between individual songs that you want to include in this playlist distance? Eg, songs by the same artist are close together. Or should the playlist distance be driven exclusively by the number/proportion of songs that are common/different in both playlists?

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen That's a good idea! I hadn't think about that. Previously, I was only thinking about number/proportion of common songs.

Comment: Do you have any particular idea about "maximum" distances between playlists? If playlist A and B have 1 different song in each, and playlists C and D have 100 different songs in each, should d(A,B) be greater, equal, or less than d(C,D)?

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen I was actually wondering if there was a pre-established distance function that works reasonably well in such cases (the space of set of objects). To answer your first question, I guess the maximum distance can be attained when there is no common song, and it could be defined as either infinity (or we can map it to 1 using $\frac 2\pi \arctan$ function) or it could be a finite number depending on the size of playlists. For your second question, it does not really matter for me, as long as the distance works somewhat well enough.

Comment: Jaccard distance?